# Nested Component binding empty

Tags: angular

I am trying to understand property binding and it has been very confusing, I was able to solve my console full of errors, but I cannot figure out why my binding 
**app.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <app-game-control [childTitle]="parentSelector"></app-game-control>
      </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  parentSelector = "This shall pass from parent to child" ;

}
```

**game-control.component.html**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-game-control',
  templateUrl: './game-control.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game-control.component.css']
})
export class GameControlComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() childTitle:string ;
title= "Hello from child component";

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**game-control.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      {{title}}
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your passed in parameter name is `childTitle`. You are using the  property `title`. Instead you should be using the input property in your game-control.component.html `{{childTitle}}`

Comment: @LLai I am confused, can you explain more.

Comment: @Nofel In your `game-control.component.html` you define your input property `childTitle`. To use the input parameter in `game-control.component` you have to use the name of that parameter so `this.childTitle` in your typescript or `childTitle` in your template html. `title` in `game-control.component` is a totally different property.

Comment: `ngOnChanges` has to be implemented in this component to have the value `GameControlComponent `

Comment: @Aravind ngOnChanges is there just bcoz I had used cli to create the component

Comment: @LLai but binding happens in app.component.html, the game-control.component.html is just for testing.

Comment: @Nofel yes you are binding the `parentSelector` property (of the `app.component`) to the `childTitle` property (of `game-control.component`) by doing `[childTitle]="parentSelector"`. I am confused, what output are you expecting? The passed value should appear in `game-control.component.html`?

Answer (score 2):

All is right in your code, the only thing is that you dont display your "childTitle" input at all.
Try this:

**game-control.component.html**

```
<div class="column">
    <div>
      <h1>Data from game-control component
      {{title}}
  </div>
  <div>
      <h1>Data from parent</h1>
      {{childTitle}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! So basically u make nested components to assign parent value e.g like sending or setting a variable, from parent to child.? I choose above example to be simplest because I had struggled to learn @Input

Comment: Yes basically, you will have smart component (parent holding the logic for the data: get data from server, update etc...) and dumb component who don't know anything about your application (Reusable component), data are passed in with Input and event emited via Output.
Here is a blog post about this topic: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-smart-components-vs-presentation-components-whats-the-difference-when-to-use-each-and-why/